# Google doesnt crawl app-ads.txt file within 24 hours

Tags: admob

I received mail from AdMob "Google titled AdMob is launching support for app-ads.txt" just like everyone. And I took the following steps.

- Visit app-ads-txt.com
- Register an account
- Add your application
- Generate your APP-ADS.TXT
- Publish your APP-ADS.TXT: You will get one link to publish on your Developer Console (Store listing Website option) and wait 24 hours.

After 3 days still status as below - "app-ads.txt file not found
"

[image]

> Here is my domain/app-ads.txt

[image]

I am using the same url for many different applications. Could that be the problem?

Or should I copy and paste the snippet directly from the admob. I need to change something?

I am stuck on this problem. I would appreciate it if someone is experiencing this problem or can help.

Comment: Where on the Google Developer Console did your place your URL?

Comment: Contact information -> Website @AlexeySubbota

Comment: @6155031 I have the same problem. I used app-ads-txt.com to generate my domain, Admob has detected the domain but report "the app-ads file text not found". Have your problem resolved?

Comment: @AnhTuan, yes it has!

Answer (score 5):

Google approved my txt file after 8 days. According to the mail they returned, this period could exceed 24 hours and it was normal for him to reach 7 days. It's really interesting that they make it compulsory and want it to happen in such a short time. Although it takes 7 days for approval.

Comment: Hmm, that is so misleading. I end up purchase a domain and a hosting in order to host that app-ads file, thinking there is a problem with the app-ads-txt.com website.